# Error with Open CV v3.1 in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, opencv3.1

I am doing a school project where I need to use OpenCV.

I try to use the function "findcontours", provided by OpenCV.
But when I call the function I systematically get an error, the program ends.
Without giving me any advice or error message.

I put you the part of the code that makes an error down there.
Ask me if you need to see something else in my code.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Detect the contour of the image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="imgCannyEdges_loc">Image made with Canny.</param>
    /// <returns>VectorOfVectorOfPointF</returns>
    public VectorOfVectorOfPointF detectContourInImage(Image<Gray, byte> imgCannyEdges_loc)
    {
        VectorOfVectorOfPointF vvpfListOfPoints = new VectorOfVectorOfPointF();

        CvInvoke.FindContours(imgCannyEdges_loc, vvpfListOfPoints, null, RetrType.List, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxNone);

        return vvpfListOfPoints;
    }
```

And here I put you the part of my code where I create and change the image. This same image will be used in my function, that I gave you just above.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Analysis with contour and with OpenCV.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="btmImage_loc">The bitmap of the image that the user wants to analys</param>
    /// <param name="dblThreshold_loc">The threshold defined by the user.</param>
    /// <param name="bReverse_loc">If the image needs to be reversed (black and white).</param>
    /// <param name="bPreview_loc">If we are asking for a preview or not.</param>
    /// <param name="iAnalysisPrecision_loc">The precision of the analysis.</param>
    /// <returns>The image, resized, and with the different change.</returns>
    public Image<Gray, Byte> thresholdingOpenCV(Bitmap btmImage_loc, double dblThreshold_loc,
        bool bReverse_loc, bool bPreview_loc, int iAnalysisPrecision_loc)
    {
        Image<Bgr, Byte> imgResized_loc;
        if (bPreview_loc == true)
        {
            imgResized_loc = new Image<Bgr, byte>(btmImage_loc).Resize(297, 210, Inter.Linear, true);
        }
        else
        {
            imgResized_loc = new Image<Bgr, byte>(btmImage_loc).Resize(297 * iAnalysisPrecision_loc,
                210 * iAnalysisPrecision_loc, Inter.Linear, true);
        }

        Image<Gray, Byte> imgCannyEdges_loc =
            (imgResized_loc.Convert<Gray, Byte>()).Canny(Math.Pow(dblThreshold_loc, 1.3), Math.Pow(dblThreshold_loc, 1.3));

        imgCannyEdges_loc.SmoothGaussian(3);
        if (bReverse_loc)
            return imgCannyEdges_loc;
        else
            return imgCannyEdges_loc.Not();
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help, and don't forget to ask me questions if something is not clear enough.

Alexander Wohlfahrt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
It was about the VectorOfVectorOf**PointF**.
findcontours, don't search for PointF but for **Point**.
In summary: use VectorOfVectorOf**Point** (Not VectorOfVectorOf**PointF**)